# permissions on google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

I'm just starting to learn about google apps. Right now, I have two spreadsheets and I made a script which takes data from spreadsheet B and arranges to write it to spreadsheet A. This works perfectly, however, What I need is to give copies of the spreadsheet B to several users so they can execute the script, but at the same time these users are not allowed to see or modify mannually the spreadsheet A.

Is it possible to do this? I was thinking that an alternative would be to write an standalone script that process the spreadsheet A and the script in the spreadsheet B just send a request to the standalone script, sort of server/cliente model.
Thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the Spreadsheet Bs are running under the credentials of the users they would need write access to Spreadsheet A.

What I would do is have a small script attached to the spreadsheet Bs that sends a message to via a HTTP to the script attached to Spreadsheet A (which can act as both a container bound script and a webapp) that it is ready to be processed. You would just need to maintain read privileges on the Spreadsheet B's.

If your data is small you could just post the data to spreadsheet A's script, but the quota for HTTP traffic is pretty low.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, if I am not wrong the script attached to Spreadsheet A would act always in listening mode, waiting for the data of the other spreadsheets. Do you have any example or tutorial to do that functionality?